# AWS RDS PostgreSQL error "remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections"

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, database-connection, amazon-rds

In the dashboard I see there are currently 22 open connections to the DB instance, blocking new connections with the error:

> remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections.

I'm accessing the DB from web service API running on EC2 instance and always keep the best practise of:

```java
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
Class.forName(DB_CLASS);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL_Query_String);
...
resultSet.close();
statement.close();
connection.close();
```

1. Can I do something else in the code?
2. Should I do something else in the DB management?
3. Is there a way to periodically close connections?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Amazon has to set the number of connections based on each model's right to demand a certain amount of memory and connections

```
MODEL      max_connections innodb_buffer_pool_size
---------  --------------- -----------------------
t1.micro   34                326107136 (  311M)
m1-small   125              1179648000 ( 1125M,  1.097G)
m1-large   623              5882511360 ( 5610M,  5.479G)
m1-xlarge  1263            11922309120 (11370M, 11.103G)
m2-xlarge  1441            13605273600 (12975M, 12.671G)
m2-2xlarge 2900            27367833600 (26100M, 25.488G)
m2-4xlarge 5816            54892953600 (52350M, 51.123G)
```

But if you want you can change the max connection size to custom value by

From RDS Console > Parameter Groups > Edit Parameters,

You can change the value of the max_connections parameter to a custom value.

For closing the connections periodically you can setup a cron job some thing like this.

```
select pg_terminate_backend(procpid)
from pg_stat_activity
where usename = 'yourusername'
 and current_query = '<IDLE>'
 and query_start < current_timestamp - interval '5 minutes';
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to periodically close connections?

Comment: Thanks, by the way - how can I add cron job in AWS RDS? Thanks,

Comment: Well you will have to run that from your local or some server.

Comment: I have EC2/Elastic beanstalk env. Is there a way to run from there? never coded cron job... Thanks,

Comment: First you will have to make sure you can access the RDS from that instance. And setting up cron job is very easy just google running cron job for a script file you will find tons of documentation.

Comment: Where did this table of info come from? A reference link would be helpful. Some of it is out of date and there are more instance versions and types now, e.g. m5

Comment: In the AWS console, RDS -> Parameter Groups -> <your param group>
I see the default postgres 11 setting is now `LEAST({DBInstanceClassMemory/9531392},5000)` so it caps it as 5000. Is it unwise to exceed the cap?

Comment: @error2007s "Error saving: Cannot modify a default parameter group. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue" is the error I get when changing it

Comment: Here is the official source for # of connections : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Managing.Performance.html

Answer (score 12):

I'm using Amazon RDS, SCALA, **Postgresql & Slick**. First of all - number of available connections in RDS depends on the amount of available **RAM** - i.e. size of the RDS instance. It's best **not to change the default conn number**.

You can check the max connection number by executing the following SQL statement on your RDS DB instance:

```
show max_connections;
```

Check your SPRING configuration to see **how many threads** you're spawning:

```
database {
  dataSourceClass = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
  properties = {
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://test.cb1111.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:6666/dbtest"
    user = "youruser"
    password = "yourpass"
  }
  numThreads = 90
}
```

All of the connections **ARE made** upon SRING BOOT **initialization** so beware not to cross the RDS limit. That includes other services that connect to the DB. In this case the number of connections will be 90+.

The current limit for db.t2.small is **198** (4GB of RAM)

[image]

Comment: Good answer actually

Answer (score 9):

You can change in the parameter group `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` to remove idle connections.

> idle_in_transaction_session_timeout (integer)
>
> Terminate any session with an open transaction that has been idle for
> longer than the specified duration in milliseconds. This allows any
> locks held by that session to be released and the connection slot to
> be reused; it also allows tuples visible only to this transaction to
> be vacuumed. See Section 24.1 for more details about this.
>
> The default value of 0 disables this feature.

The current value in AWS RDS is `86400000` which when converted to hours (86400000/1000/60/60) is 24 hours.

Answer (score 5):

you can change the max connections in the `Parameters Group` for your RDS instance. Try to increase it.
Or you can try to upgrade your instance, as the max connexions is set to `{DBInstanceClassMemory/31457280}`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to periodically close connections?